# Powershell.exe with many parameters (in Batch) - Error Ampersand not allowed

Tags: powershell, powercli

I have a batch file, which calls the PowerCLI:

```
powershell –noexit -command "&{add-pssnapin vmware.vimautomation.core; $host.ui.rawui.WindowTitle='PowerCLI'}"
```

But I want to add more stuff on the command line, make a junction with another command I have:

```
powershell.exe -command "& c:\scripts\Cluster.ps1 -vimHost %1 -vimuser %2 -vimpass %3" %4
```

I tried to put all parameters in a single line to Powershell but it did not work:

```
c:\> powershell -version 2.0 –noexit -command "&{add-pssnapin vmware.vimautomation.core; $host.ui.rawui.WindowTitle='PowerCLI'}" .\scripts\Cluster_v1.ps1 -vimHost %1 -vimuser %2 -vimpass %3" %4
```

***Ampersand not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; use "&" to pass ampersand as a string.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmpersandNotAllowed***

How can I get concatenate the various parameters in powershell command?

Comment: Put the commands in a script and run the script using `-File`.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for "Put the commands in a script and run the script using -File."

But I got curious and mocked up a small batch example that worked okay on PS v3. Just in case this helps track down your problem, I have three files in one directory:

"psScriptFile.ps1" with contents:

```
param([string]$File,[string]$echoMe)
gci $file | select length | ft -auto
$echoMe
```

"so.bat" with contents:

```
powershell -noExit -command "&{add-pssnapin vmware.vimautomation.core; $host.ui.rawui.WindowTitle='PowerCLI';.\psScriptFile.ps1 -file someFile.lala 'maybe extra quotes gotcha?'}"
```

and "someFile.lala" whose contents are irrelevant. If you can recreate your problem in an example on [that](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) scale, we're more likely to help.

Answer (score 0):

powershell -command "&{add-pssnapin vmware.vimautomation.core;c:\scripts\BuscaHostCluster_v1.ps1 -Vcenter %1 -Vuser %2 -Vpass %3 %4}"

Tanks!